# Trigger does not support scheduler job in Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, triggers, scheduler, jobs, oracle19c

Trigger does not support scheduler job in Oracle 19c.

I created "After Create or Alter" trigger on database to monitor and backup Oracle Database objects'(table, stored procedures, etc.) changes(who, when, where, what) when someone create or modify them. However, it cannot triggers when a scheduler job is created or modified.

How to auto-backup Oracle scheduler job, when it is created or modified?

Comment: Jobs are not schema objects, so they do not raise [DDL events](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B) to be captured by triggers. However why are you trying to implement your own backup solution instead of Oracle supplied (and thoroughly tested) tools like RMAN, for example?

Comment: More precisely, I do not simply backup Oracle objects. I want to monitor everyone's  modifications to Oracle objects(table, stored procedures, etc.) and auto-commit to Git repository every day for version controlling, which needs trigger to record the DDL once someone modifies or creates Oracle stuff.

Comment: I think it should go reverse way: changes -> VCS -> deployment (DB). With additional DB instance that will receive changes (not the same as development). For your particular question: I don't know any (good) solution, perhaps, it should be asked in https://dba.stackexchange.com/